# dividing a numeric variable in sas

Tags: sas

Say I have data called data and a variable age
and I am looking for a way to divide the variable representing age, in to a new variable showing the age group meaning,18-21,21-24 and so on.
I know how to do it with proc sql and if, but  I understand there is an efficient way to do it using the round function.

Does anybody know how you can divide a numeric variable using round?

thanks.

Comment: You should show some attempt at doing this yourself to be a valid SO question.  Have you also considered creating a format to display the data?  That way you don't need a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

**Method1:** Using **If/Else**
**Method2:** Using **Proc format**
I have shared the code for method2 as you already know method1

```
proc format;
value age
low - 9 = '0 - 9'  
10 - 19 = '10 - 19'
20 - 29 = '20 - 29'
30 - 39 = '30 - 39'
40 - 49 = '40 - 49'
50 - 59 = '50 - 59'
60 - high = '60 +++'
;
run;


/**1) If you just want to look at age in bucket form         **/
    data abc;
    set abc;
    format age age.;
    run;    

/**2) If you want to create another variable(say age_bucket)  **/
    data abc;
    set abc;
    age_bucket = put(age,age.);
    run;
```

Let me know in case of any queries.